# Checking the functions that need to be used by a script in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a package of code that's been written by someone else. I am running a script, which calls some functions, which in turn calls some more functions, etc. I would like to get the list of functions that are not MATLAB built-in functions but are a part of the package.

I tried using `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('file.m')`, which gives me a list of such functions, but not all the functions. I can see when I look at the code that there are many more functions called by a function in the script. Does this command only show 'first-level' functions? How can I get the full list?

Comment: One possibility would be to use the profiler (e.g. [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html). It will list all functions that the programme calls during its execution.

Comment: This toolbox (m2html) http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/ seems to list all functions called within a function, for example see its own documentation as in http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the function [inmem](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inmem.html) which may help to solve this task. It displays all matlab functions that are currently in memory. Thus it lists those functions that have been recently called, i.e. that have been called since the last `clear all`or `clear functions` statement. Thus you would start with a clean workspace, execute your program, and check with `inmem` which functions are loaded into the cache and are not in the matlab install directory, those are the functions you are interested in.

You may also use the command-line helper [`disp-inmem`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10459-disp-inmem) that was scripted to (half-)automate this task.

Answer (score 2):

This function performs well, but isn't guaranteed to get all files. Works fine for me though

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15484-recursively-get-file-dependencies-of-a-given-function/content/getFileDependencies.m

Comment: Do we know why it's not guaranteed to get all files? Or in what cases it would miss some?

Comment: This gives the same output as `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts` and gives the following warning:

`Warning: DEPFUN will be removed in a future release. Use
matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts instead. `