# How can I determine which routines MATLAB uses to solve a full(dense) matrix?

Tags: matlab

How do we know what algorithm does MATLAB choose internally to:

> Solve systems of linear equations xA = B for x

```
x = B/Aexample
x = mrdivide(B,A)

%example dataset:
A = [1 1 3; 2 0 4; -1 6 -1];
B = [2 19 8];
x = B/A
x =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
```

The documentation says it has a full comparison on the A matrix on various criteria before it decides what solver to use, is there any way to get a complete diagnostic output of this calculation?

PS: For sparse matricies, we can use `spparms('key',value)`.

Comment: `mldivide` has a flow chart: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

Comment: Yes, but there is a way to let matlab output what are the decision outputs just like using spparms on sparse matrix.

Comment: @AnderBiguri   See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314476/how-can-i-determine-which-routines-matlab-uses-to-solve-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: There doesn't seem an obvious way of doing this. You may write your own knowing the flowchart maybe....